# Dataframe to JSON for grouped data in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a dataframe that looks a bit like this:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'business_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
              'year':[2010,2011,2012,2010,2011,2012,2010,2011,2012],
             'number_staff':[3,4,5,4,3,5,6,5,8],
             'ave_turnover_in_k':[10,12,13,13,10,17,16,15,17]})
```

And I'd like it to look like this:

```
{  
   "1":{  
      "number_staff":{  
         "2010":3,
         "2011":4,
         "2012":5
      },
      "ave_turnover_in_k":{  
         "2010":10,
         "2011":12,
         "2012":13
      }
   },
   "2":{  
      "number_staff":{  
         "2010":4,
         "2011":3,
         "2012":5
      },
      "ave_turnover_in_k":{  
         "2010":13,
         "2011":10,
         "2012":17
      }
   },
   "3":{  
      "number_staff":{  
         "2010":6,
         "2011":5,
         "2012":8
      },
      "ave_turnover_in_k":{  
         "2010":16,
         "2011":15,
         "2012":17
      }
   }
}
```

I've got my list of businesses:

```
business = list(set(list(my_df.iloc[:,1])))
business
```

And I've got my number of staff for one business as an example to the create a dictionary for one business:

```
no_staff = my_df.loc[my_df['business_id'] == 1].iloc[:,[3,2]]
no_staff
no_staff_dict = {list(no_staff.columns.values)[1]:no_staff.set_index('year').T.to_dict('records')[0]}
no_staff_dict
```

But I can't work out how to iterate over all the businesses, and then add that data in to the list of businesses so that the business ID remains a key and the variables are values.

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward solution:

```
def dt_to_json(df):
  d = {}
  for i,j in zip(df['business_id'], range(len(df['year']))):
    if str(i) not in d:           
        d[str(i)] = {
            "number_staff": { str(df['year'][j]): df['number_staff'][j] },
            "ave_turnover_in_k": { str(df['year'][j]): df['ave_turnover_in_k'][j] }
        }
    else:
        d[str(i)]['number_staff'][str(df['year'][j])] = df['number_staff'][j]
        d[str(i)]['ave_turnover_in_k'][str(df['year'][j])] = df['ave_turnover_in_k'][j]
  return d
```

If you pass your `DataFrame` to this function you will get your `JSON` object, but your `string`s will be wrapped in single quotes. So, after you run `dt_to_json(df)`'s output through this:

```
str(dt_to_json(df)).replace("'", "\"")
```

you will get valid JSON. I've tried this with your `DataFrame` and pasted the output [here](http://jsonprettyprint.com/) to check the result, and it worked.

### Note

There might be more elegant solution with build-in function like [to_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html), but I'm not too familiar with `pandas`.